# Properties of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\liminf_{j \to \infty} a_j = c$. What kind of properties do I know have for $a_j$? It seems that now there exists $j_0$ such that $a_j \ge c + \varepsilon$, when $j \ge j_0$ but isn’t this due to the infimum and not $\liminf$? Also is there similar properties for $\limsup_{j \to \infty} a_j$? That is does it hold that if $$\limsup_{j \to \infty} a_j  = a$$ then $\exists j_0$ such that $a- \varepsilon \le a_j$, when $j \ge j_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Both your inequalities are wrong.

For the liminf, you should have $a_j \ge c - \varepsilon$ for all $j\geq j_0$.  How you've written it implies $\lim a_j = \infty$.

For the limsup, you should have $a_j \leq a + \varepsilon$ for all $j\geq j_0$.  How you've written it implies $\liminf a_j \geq a$

Comment: Seems that I’ve mixed the $+$ and $-$. Also isn’t these two properties due to the infimum and supremum and not the limit infimum or limit supremum?

Comment: It's not just the signs.  Your inequality under limsup is backwards.  The fact you're letting $j_0$ depend on $\varepsilon >0$ and then only looking at $j\geq j_0$ is what makes it a liminf/limsup.  Also, note that after correcting the signs, it's possible you might have $a_n < \liminf_{j\to\infty}a_j$ for every $n$, which looks nothing like the infimum of the $a_j$.